# Should i use multi-threading? (retrieving mass data from APIs)

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python script which gathers 10,000's of 'people' from an API and then goes on to request two other APIs to gather further data about them and then save the information to a local database, it takes around 0.9 seconds per person.

So at the moment it will take a very long time to complete. Would multi-threading help to speed this up? I tried a multi-threading test locally and it was slower, but this test was just a simple function without any API interaction or anything web/disk related.

thanks

Comment: What API are you talking about?

Comment: Assuming the API hits a remote server or a "slow" local resource like disk-bound database, *and* assuming your client itself has spare resources, concurrency is probably the way to go.

Comment: You should look up the python GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). I haven't tested myself for performance, but I expect that Python a scripts' performance won't improve much at all by adding more threads. I/O bound threads will do better than compute bound threads - so if your script is mostly IO bound then adding threads will most likely improve its performance. For compute bound scripts, multi-processing will do better -- run the script in several processes with each doing a bit of the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many cores do you have?

How parallelizable is the process?

Is the problem CPU bound?

If you have several cores and it's parallelizable across them, you're likely to get a speed boost. The overhead for multithreading isn't nearly 100% unless implemented awfully, so that's a plus.

On the other hand, if the slow part is CPU bound it might be a lot more fruitful to look into a C extension or Cython. Both of those at times can give a 100× speedup (sometimes more, often less, depending on how numeric the code is) for much less effort than a 2× speed-up with naïve usage of `multiprocessing`. Obviously the 100× speedup is only for the translated code.

But, seriously, profile. Chances are there are low hanging fruit that are much easier to access than any of this. Try a line profiler (say, the one called `line_profiler` [also called `kernprof`]) and the builtin cProfile.

Comment: 4 cores.

I don't see how it could be limited, there are already checks in place to prevent duplicates being gathered.

CPU load is very low, I think the main wait time is the external APIs

Comment: Then you should parallelize the API calls, which basic threading (see `threading` or the newer `concurrent.futures`) would deal with much more readily. Multiple processes mean nothing if you aren't CPU bound.

Comment: The whole of the task would really need to be threaded I think, since the 'people' are part of a higher up category. They are retrieved after it is, and there's about 2 million categories.

Comment: I think this answer is leaving out one big issue: Roundtrip latency. If you request some data and then wait for a response, this will cost you at least as much as a ping requires. If you spend the time waiting for a response by sending further requests, you are making better use of the network. If you have lots of small request/response pairs, the roundtrip latency could be the performance killer in a naïve design.